# Impossible make a input or AtomTextEditor with React

Tags: atom-editor

I'm making a plugin that gets the actual panel or text selection and runs a command on the cli with that value and some params that the user adds in a input.

The idea is to have a similar view than `find-and-replace` package, but from the first beginning I wasn't able to use `space-pane-views` for a error on jQuery.
So I decided to make it with React and as far as I was making everything was okayish, but I found 2 big problems.

First I understand what's the `View` of `space-pan` and all the ShadowDOM that uses, I feel that is not compatible with React at all, is some kind of big Model that gets data from the dom and from some methods.

So I created a `<input />` and I figuret out that you can't interact as normal as a website with that input, doesn't have the hability of delete normally the text and you can't use the `atom-text-editor` styles into it.

in another hand I try to create a Custom Web Component with React like:

```
<atom-text-editor
  {...this.props}
  mini
  tabindex='-1'
  class={`${this.props.className}`}
  data-grammar='text plain null-grammar'
  data-encoding='utf8'
/>
```

and it works with inheriting the styles, but I can't access to the content of the Shadow DOM, neither add eventHandlers like `onChange` (`onKeyPress` works btw), this is basically a problem more than React that Atom, but is as far as I went in the intention to create a View in Atom.

Another option could be add `draft-js` from Fb, but it's a crazy idea for create a simple input.

Any idea to solve one of both problems?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a normal input in React with `className='native-key-bindings'` the input contains the nativew key bindings, and you can attach the eventHandlers there.